# Estimating Probability Estimate of low sample data

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, predictive-models

I have a problem pertaining practical real-life situation we encounter quite often.

Lets say I have a e-commerce site selling clothes. There is a particular shirt which was sent N units to the warehouse and let's say few of them were bought online.

SO here are the questions:

1). What would be the estimate of future probability of selling of this shirt and the no. of units we can estimate to be sold in future.

2). If the no. of units are lets say 10 and we sold 10 of them, this is a low sample problem and sample estimate here is like 1.0, but that can't be correctly used to estimate the probability parameter.  How to estimate the future probability of selling of this shirt.

3). How to get an estimate for a completely new product which doesn't have any sales yet.

4). In general if someone buys 5 products. Normally if the items are independent of each other we can estimate the sales by taking the sum of probabilities times the no. of units etc. But in practice items are not bought independently, hence the probability distribution of each of these 5 items is not independent. In this case how can one get an estimate

Comment: Predicting at SKU level is very difficult because of the sparsity of data, that is why one should try to model at higher hierarchy and then if needed, try bring that down to SKU level. In a retail setup, I have seen recommendation systems built with category-level sales data and then broken down to SKU as per user-preference work better than model trained with SKU-level sales data.

Comment: So in my view your solution would require model-training at some higher-hierarchy of products and then using brand, size preferences and such to bring it to SKU level. For cold-start problem, you have to use meta-data about products to find very similar existing products.

Comment: Can you explain the 4th point more clearly? Why do you want to take the sum of probability * quantity? All you want is sales forecast and Probability of sale right for each SKU, right?

Comment: This is not a question about machine learning. The first 3 questions deal with basic Statistics way of estimating a population parameter when there is not much data

Comment: You can always calculate the expected value of random variables using small samples. Its the confidence interval that is bigger when sample is small. So, there's only one way to get better estimates, getting a bigger sample. As you cannot do anything about the data, what one can do is to use data from different SKUs that are very similar to each other, in order to get better estimates of probability. The same can be used to get estimates for totally new products

Comment: SKU = Stock Keeping Unit